# browser.click() does not work in redactor buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, selenium, protractor, redactor

Have anybody tried doing an automated test involving redactor? I have a problem with `browser.click()`. It will not click the button I want it to click eg. the bold, italicised or underline buttons. Can someone help me?

Attached image below shows the DOM elements in dev tools. In my locator, eg. for bold, i used `('.red-bold').click();`

[image]

Comment: What exactly is happening when you try to click the, say, bold button - any errors? And, how are you locating the button?

Comment: hi, if you look at the just attached image above, i used the class. so eg. for bold, i used ( '.class' ).click(), it does not return any error but it does not click the button. even tried in browser console in using jquery, it will not click the button. but it can locate the element though.

Comment: `.red-bold`? did you make a typo here or in code? - should be `.re-bold` :)

Answer (score 0):

There is probably something wrong with your code. In any case, here is an example working code that selects all the text inside the [`redactor` editor](https://imperavi.com/redactor/), clicks the "B" button in the toolbar making all the text bold:

```
describe("Redactor demo test", function () {
    var editor;

    beforeEach(function () {
        var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;

        browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
        browser.get("https://imperavi.com/redactor/");

        // wait for the redactor editor to become visible
        editor = $(".redactor-editor");
        browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(editor), 5000);
    });

    it("should make the text bold", function () {
        // select all text in the editor
        editor.click();
        editor.sendKeys(protractor.Key.COMMAND, "a");

        // click "bold"
        var toolbar = $(".redactor-toolbar");
        toolbar.$(".re-bold").click();

        browser.sleep(30000);  // the delay is for you to see it becomes bold 
        // TODO: expectations
    });
});
```